# Detect when Angular has finished changing the template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Assume I have this template for my component :

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" #genericTable>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="#column of columns | slice:0:7">{{column.Label}}</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="#row of rows">
                <td *ngFor="#data of row.Datas | slice:0:7">
                    <div *ngIf="!data.Value">Aucun</div>
                    <div *ngIf="data.Value">{{data.Value}}</div>
                </td>
                <td><a [routerLink]="['Details', {table: tableName, id: row.Id}]">Details</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The goal of this template is to render a table following some informations coming from a Web service. Thanks to Angular, I can pull datas asynchronously and, with change detection, render my array of "columns" and "rows". It works like a charm.

Now I need to execute some code just after Angular has changed my template and has rendered my datas. How is that possible ?
Thanks

Comment: There isn't really a way. Probably some ugly workaround. Why would you need that?

Comment: `ngAfterViewChecked` and some logic inside of it

Comment: We use a jQuery plugin for paging, searching ... and I need to apply the plugin only when the table is fully rendered.

Comment: Thanks @EricMartinez `ngAfterViewChecked ` worked !

Answer (score -1):

If you are needing to interact with specific elements in the page after it is rendered or just after the data is calculated? If its after data you can use ng-init or ng-class. ng-class may work on render. Write a function in scope and pass it in. I have a metric processor that runs on ng-class and updates labels, green for good red for bad.

```
 actionFunction: function(){
 //interact with page here
 angular.element(document).find(...); 
 };
```

In directive

```
ng-init="actionFunction()"
```

or

```
ng-class="actionFuncton()"
```

Comment: That doesn't look like Angular2.